# Meditation, sleep paralysis, spinal vibration

Tags: meditation-insight, meditation-effects, consciousness, teachers

I have meditated off and on since childhood, before I knew what it was, and since my 30s I have been interested in the spiritual concepts of Buddhism.  I had an experience in 2010 wherein I awoke from sleep but could not move, yet my eyes were open, not my physical eyes.  I could see a pale ceiling but could not look around.  I was aware of my cat half-lying on my stomach, and he was purring.  My ears popped, and suddenly I could hear differently, acutely.  I heard footsteps ascending my stairs and the swishing sound like that of a robe.  I heard footsteps cross to the left side of the bed.  I was frightened, and the hair stood up on end on my arms and head, but I deepened my breathing and relaxed.  I immediately felt a type of massaging, but not on my physical body, more the ethereal body, and also a warmth.  The light massaging moved from left leg and foot to right leg and foot to left rib area to right rib area, and then I heard movement toward my head.  The light in front of my eyes suddenly brightened, and my sinus passages popped loudly.  I felt gentle pressure like hands cradling under my neck, and this pressure began to lift my head and shoulders upward, and I knew that I was being assisted out of body.  Then my alarm went off and awakened me.  I sensed a vibrational peace which lasted several minutes.  Since that time, I have had several OOB experiences, always as I go to sleep or am awakening from sleep, some frightening, which set me back for a few years.

Recently, over the last 2 years, I have had several experiences after I fall asleep wherein I half awaken in that state again, and sometimes feel a presence near, but immediately I feel a very strong, pleasant, vibrational, almost humming flow of energy flowing from the base of my neck to the base of my spine and back again.  I always fall back asleep easily.

I don't know what is happening, and I have been trying to release any fear and simply let it be.  I want to trust that this is some type of healing or spiritual progression process, but I feel that I have no guidance.  Are there any Buddhist teachers who would be able to guide me through this? Any response or feedback would be extremely welcome!

Comment: Sounds like some effect of Dream Yoga practise? I remember reading something about practising Dream Yoga with some natural light experience.

Comment: Thank you ~ I haven't heard of Dream Yoga and will look into it.

Comment: It is worth being aware of the potentially adverse effects of meditation on people with a history of trauma. There is a small but growing awareness of this phenomenon in the scientific community. See, e.g. the work of Willoughby Britton (  [here](https://www.mindful.org/willoughby-britton-the-messy-truth-about-mindfulness/) and [here](https://www.brown.edu/research/labs/britton/research/varieties-contemplative-experience) ) as well as [David Treleaven's work](https://www.davidtreleaven.com/).

Comment: Thank you, Shiri, for your advice, and I will look into these author's works.  I have just begun reading Dream Yoga and the Practice of Natural Light, revised.  My experiences continue, and I cannot help but feel that these are occurring for a reason; however, I will continue with utmost caution.

Comment: Good luck, V Beth. Please take good care of yourself and don't push yourself too hard. Remember that part of the path is also loving kindness and compassion to yourself <3

Comment: Thank you for the gentle reminder, Shiri, and I will do so <3   I have begun reading Willoughby Britton and Treleaven's works, and they remind me of Living with Kundalini, Autobiography of Gopi Krishna, which provides a beautiful yet sometimes harrowing account of the power of meditation and transformation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dont be too much stuck with spiritual experiences.

What you explained accounts for nothing except that now you know what all things are there beyond normal experiences.

Since you have asked this question on a buddhist stack exchange I will suggest you explore more on meditation and start meditating.

There is lit more to experience.

Comment: Thank you for your response which has reminded me that these experiences have offered a most valuable realization, which is simply that I now know, in a complete sense and not only an intellectual sense, that energy/consciousness does not cease to be as in a concept of death, but transforms, transmutes, and continues.  I will explore more regarding meditation and practice more consistently.  Have you found it beneficial to join a sangha?

Comment: @VBeth Congrats now you know for sure and this trust will foster your practise. Joining a sangha is benificial depending on where you are and the honesty and authenticity of teacher. But since you are honest you will find a honest teacher. It always helps to be guided on the path.

Answer (score 0):

There is not much guidance to give apart from what you already posted, namely,  to release any fear and simply let it be.

What is occurring is during sleep; where the intellectual facility appears to be half asleep and half awake; is possible & ordinary. For example, I have experienced real wisdom engaging during dreams (generally about death); where wisdom engages and reflects: "*This is only a dream*".

As for the sensations, this is just mental formations moving around & arising to purify (what you call: "*humming flow of energy flowing*"). Again, there is not much guidance to give apart from what you already posted, namely,  to release any fear and simply let it be.

Often, when my body-mind have releases of energy during sleep, the mind has dreams of literally flying in the sky; over oceans & cities at night; which is extremely enjoyable & refreshing. The mind can do these things because this is the creative or imaginative nature of the mind; that is all.

Also, the Buddhist scriptures mention supernormal mental occurrences, such as visions and perception of external events (called 'Divine Eye' & 'Divine Ear'). All of these things are mere possible mental happenings; that require release of any fear and simply let it be.

The core teaching of Buddhism is "*non-attachment*" towards all experience.

> *When a monk has heard that nothing is worth clinging to, he directly knows everything; having directly known everything, he fully
> understands everything; having directly known everything, he fully
> understood everything, whatever feeling he feels, whether pleasant or
> painful or neither pleasant or painful, he abides contemplating
> (observing) impermanence in those feelings, contemplating (observing)
> fading away, contemplating (observing) cessation, contemplating
> (observing) relinquishment (letting go). Contemplating (observing)
> thus, he does not cling (obsess about) to anything in the world.*
>
> [*Shorter Discourse on the Destruction of Craving*](https://www.dhammatalks.net/Books9/Bhikkhu_Bodhi_Culatanhasankhaya_Sutta.htm)

Comment: Thank you for your insight, particularly regarding the reminder of the core teaching of non-attachment.  I also have had vivid dreams about flying over cities and through dark space with distant, colorful points of colored lights at a high rate of speed.  And I have been fascinated and hopeful about these experiences as they seem to be both a creative, liberating, process and also perhaps an element or part of spiritual cleansing, healing, and/or progress.  I now remind myself not to become attached to these experiences and also to meditate more regularly and consistently.

Comment: Doesn't this sound like an Kundalini awakening or qi energy?

Comment: Kundalini  & Qi are not Buddhist notions. Buddhist meditation is about non-attachment.